# Having problems with PHP Setup on CentOS 6.6

Tags: php, netbeans, installation, centos

I'm trying to get a php development environment ready to go on a virtual CentOS 6.6 computer. I have installed Netbeans, and I have httpd installed as well. However, following the tutorial found [here](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/configure-php-environment-ubuntu.html#createDocumentRootLocation) doesn't actually work for me. When I go to run the program, I get a 404 error. I think the issue is a bad document root directory.

Currently, httpd is set up with a special config file: a single Include that tells it to include a config file for a rather large Perl script and set the document root directory to something special (a subdirectory in /mnt). I am tasked with replacing this Perl script with a PHP script that does the same stuff, hence why I need the environment. Commenting out this Include and restarting httpd does not fix my issue.

I just installed NetBeans, and I'm hoping this is a simple fix that I've missed, as I'm not that good with Linux.

Comment: open the file /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf and look for DocumentRoot. It will show you your root directory for you webserver.

Maybe you didn't put the file in the right directory

Comment: On the host computer, have you made an entry corresponding to the IP of the VM's website in the host file?

Comment: pchmn's comment was very helpful. With that, I figured out where the root directory was for my webserver and from there set up a symlink to my netbeans project folder. Thanks for your help!

Comment: In other news, having php installed on your computer helps with php development. Whodathunkit?